# Logging into website with Mechanize - digorganized user form

Tags: python, mechanize, form-submit

I am trying to log into what i think is a poorly coded website using mechanize, and I am facing some issues.

The website forms are like the following:

```
              <tr>
                <td align="left" valign="middle" class="style3">User name </td>

                <td height="22" colspan="2" align="right" valign="middle"><input name="someLongCrap_UserName" type="text" id="someLongCrap2_UserName" class="inputborder" onkeydown="javascript:if (event.which || event.keyCode){if ((event.which == 13) || (event.keyCode == 13)) {document.getElementById(&#39;imgSubmit&#39;).focus().click();}};" /></td> 
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="left" valign="middle" class="style3">Password</td>
                <td height="22" colspan="2" align="right" valign="middle"><input name="someLongCrap_Password" type="password" id="someLongCrap2_Password" class="inputborder" onkeydown="javascript:if (event.which || event.keyCode){if ((event.which == 13) || (event.keyCode == 13)) {document.getElementById(&#39;imgSubmit&#39;).focus().click();}};" /></td>
                </tr>
              <tr>
                <td rowspan="2" align="left" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>

                <td rowspan="2" align="right" valign="bottom">
                    <a id="abcDef">
                    <input type="image" name="imgSubmit1" id="imgSubmit2"  alt="Submit" /></a>
                </td>
              </tr>
```

I have tried some different iterations of the following:

```
        from mechanize import Browser

        br = Browser()
        br.open("http://www.mysite.com")

        user = br.select_form("someLongCrap_UserName") ;
        user.set_value='myUserName';

        passw = br.select_form("someLongCrap_Password") 
        passw.set_value='myPassword';
```

And I am getting the following type of error:
`mechanize._mechanize.FormNotFoundError: no form matching name 'someLongCrap_UserName'`

I am hoping someone more familiar with mechanize might be able to tell me what I am doing wrong.

Additionally, I am also in the end looking to log in, so I would want to "click" (through mechanize) the login "Submit" button (name="imgSubmit1").

Thank you for any pointers

---

Upon running

```
                for form in br.forms():
                    print form
                    print '-------------'
```

I get these in the list of forms:
          `<TextControl(someLongCrap_UserName=)>`
          `<PasswordControl(someLongCrap_Password=)>`

But when i go to `.select_form(nr=x)`, for x>0 I get an error.
        `br.select_form(nr=0)`

If x=1;
                `mechanize._mechanize.FormNotFoundError: no form matching nr 1`

Comment: Okay I dind't quite understand what error you're getting when you use br.select_form(nr=0)  because that one should be the one

Comment: Could you post the html code from the <table> to </table> tags?

Answer (score 0):

use the index to select the form you want

like this.  first

```
for form in br.forms():
    print form
```

find out which index your form is.  ie 0 1 2 etc

then try

```
br.select.form(nr=1) #for the second form on the page for example
```

if you need to get the control names for text input just do...

```
print br.form.controls
```

then:

```
br.form['someLongCrap_UserName']='username'
br.form['someLongCrap_Password']='password'
br.submit()
```

Comment: I get the following error on the iteration: `for form in br.forms:
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object is not iterable`

Comment: sorry make it for form in br.forms():

Comment: what is 'whatevervalue' for you? the input form name? also see above with comments.

Comment: @jason m  I've updated my variable names above.  Once you successfully br.select.form(nr=????) you can use the br.form['variable']='var1 method as noted above

Comment: could I email you the full <table>? Will happily revert and post here when we find the solution. My email is in my profile, please initiate if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

I will not accept my answer as it is not the "correct" answer given the prompt I offered but [selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) is a fantastic solution to do exactly what I need. I think there might be some speed degradation using this versus mechanize, but I would need to do tests (and not having a working mechanize solution makes this tough).

Anyway, the following generalized code is what should work for you given my needs:

```
            from selenium import webdriver

            from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
            from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
            from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
            from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


            baseurl = "http://myurl.com";

            username = "myUserName"
            password = "myPassword"



            mydriver = webdriver.Firefox()
            mydriver.get(baseurl)
            mydriver.maximize_window()

            inputElement = mydriver.find_element_by_id("userNameInputBox")
            inputElement.send_keys(username)

            inputElement = mydriver.find_element_by_id("passWordInputBox");
            inputElement.send_keys(password);

            inputElement = mydriver.find_element_by_id("mySubmitButton");
            inputElement.click();
```